# WPF Combobox bug when form allowtransparency=true

Tags: wpf, transparency

I have found the following in WPF:

I have a form with AllowTransparency=true. Inside the form I put a Combobox.
I add some items to the combobox.

I run this application and click on the combobox. At first it does not seem to appear at all. On closer inspection (after adding more items) I see that it is actually appearing behind the form. If I add enough items it become visible from behind the form.

If I just change AllowTransparency=false, then all is fine.

This looks like a bug in WPF (3.5 SP1).

Any one know of a workaround for this?

Comment: Upvote from me. I have got this exact problem and not enough information is available. Have you manage to fix this problem?

Comment: No, I contacted MS support, but after I confirmed that it only happens on my dev machine and not all machines, they were not really interested in helping... Strangely enough it solved itself in the end, somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Go to 
https://connect.microsoft.com/dashboard/?wa=wsignin1.0

submit your feedback after searching @

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/CreateFeedbackForm.aspx?FeedbackFormConfigurationID=1160&FeedbackType=1

and mention steps to reproduce.

There was an update of 3.5sp1 but you could test,but I doubt

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=6c095bba-6100-4ec9-9c54-6450b0212565&displaylang=en

Answer (score 1):

AllowTransparency is slow and buggy and shouldn't be used - it's a great way to run into bug in various display drivers.

You can get almost anything you like without using AllowTrasparency, take a look at this post for examples:

http://blogs.msdn.com/wpfsdk/archive/2008/09/08/custom-window-chrome-in-wpf.aspx